# Am I rewriting Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit correctly?

Tags: module, blocks

Magento CE 1.9.2.2

I would like to rewrite **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit**.

Specifically this file: **app/code/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php**

In my custom module's etc/config.xml file I have this for the rewrite block (not actually MyCompany/MyModule):

```
<adminhtml>
  <rewrite>
    <catalog_product_edit>MyCompany_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit</catalog_product_edit>
  </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

But where this approach has worked before for overwriting other blocks, I'm now getting this PHP error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyCompany_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491
```

I think my config.xml rewrite entry might be at fault but I'm not certain.

Comment: Please check at module main config. MyCompany_MyModule.xml add your system not check compiler is enabled ornot

Comment: From the error, it looks like your configuration is working fine, and the class file can be found from the system. You probably have some sort of syntax error in your PHP file (maybe a typo in your class name? Or upper/lowercase naming issue?). What happens if you manually require your file?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, may be this will help you out. 
Config.xml for rewrite

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <My_Custom>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    </My_Custom>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <custom>
            <class>My_Custom_Block</class>
        </custom>
        <adminhtml>
           <rewrite>
               <catalog_product_grid>My_Custom_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
           </rewrite>
       </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

Code for extending class

```
class My_Custom_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit {

}
```